# Unable to find property in JNDI context using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, properties, jndi

I want to remove env-entry from WEb.XML

```
<env-entry>
    <description>String used in masking process</description>
    <env-entry-name>default_mask</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-value>*</env-entry-value>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

so I created a properties file having (c:/my.properties)

```
default_mask=9999
```

So I try to use the existing solution like JndiPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer (from [Spring Jndi Context and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998704/spring-jndi-context-and-propertyplaceholderconfigurer)
)
and configured following in spring's applicationcontext.xml as

```
<bean  
class="com.test.webappl.JndiPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/> 
<property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/> 
<property name="location" value="file:c:\my.properties"/>
```

Starting Tomcat server reads the property file like

```
.......com.test.webappl.JndiPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer] Loading properties file from URL [file:c:/my.properties]
```

Now in java when I read

```
Context context = new InitialContext(); 
String resource = context.lookup("java:comp/env/default_mask");
```

application throws following error

```
**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name default_mask is not bound in this Context**
```

also my spring setting in web.xml are

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Anybody knows if I'm using the correct way? 
I know this has been answered in [Spring Jndi Context and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998704/spring-jndi-context-and-propertyplaceholderconfigurer) but somehow not working in my case

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying anything to any application server it's a good idea to package all relevant resources to the deployment unit (war in your case).

To answer your question - if you're using spring to inject anything to the JNDI container, you should also let spring locate everything for you.

So you can't use

```
new InitialContext(); // this has nothing to do with spring.
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying (or expecting) to do is "Bind the name value pairs from your `my.properties` to JNDI context".

**BUT**

The example that you referred does not DO that. Is simply does following things

1. If there is a property placeholder referred in the context file  (like `${my.name}`), then it will resolve it from JNDI (assuming its already there)
2. If its not available from JNDI then resolve it to some default read from a property file.
3. Nowhere its details about Binding variables to JNDI. There is no reference to `bind()` method.

Now,
     **To solve your problem** i.e. get some way of reading the properties file and bind that to JNDI tree, one way would be following

1. You can create a class `JndiPropertyBinder` and inject `jndiTemplate` in it.
2. Inject your property file in this class
3. Now write a [init hook](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-init-method-and-destroy-method-example/) on the bean where in it will read all the property in the file and bind them to jndi tree.
4. Make this bean to load very early in order so that its loaded before all the other beans which are using it.

Comment: still, will this solution work with plain new InitialContext() ?? Don't you have to look properties up from Spring itself?

Comment: The `plain new InitialContext()` will still work. JNDI is not part of spring. Its a different entity.`InitialContext` lets you interact with JNDI Tree. In fact the jndiTemplate internally uses 'InitialContext`. See [this](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/2.5.2/spring-2.5.2-sources.jar!/org/springframework/jndi/JndiTemplate.java?format=ok) link

Comment: Tomcat is throwing error where try to bind the key/value @java:comp/env.......Context is read only

Comment: Oh yes. Local JNDI context is read-only. Meanwhile I figure out this, I want to understand why you want those variables from JNDI, you can pick them from normal property file in spring via standard `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` ?

Comment: Actually, our application reads the env variable from Initial context using JNDI java:comp/env/xxxxx, now we just want to move/override them to external properties file, w/o changing the application internals to retrieve them