# PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in Spring combined for JNDI and Property File

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to read properties from two places:

a) A JNDI entry with `jndi-name` `environment/config` configured on WebSphere server as a resource environment entry.

```
my.color.property=abc
my.size.property=pqr
```

b) A properties file `config.properties` on my class path.

```
propa=xyz
propb=def
propc=mno
```

I want some way to read all the above 5 properies (2 from JNDI and 3 from property file) as `PropertiesArray`.

I found the following way to do it for the JNDI:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="myJndiProperties" jndi-name="environment/config" expected-type="java.util.Properties"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
   <property name="propertiesArray">
        <list>
          <ref bean="myJndiProperties" />                    
        </list>
   </property>
   <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Now autowiring `myJndiProperties` in my class and then using it as below gives the property entries from JNDI:

```
@Autowired
private Properties myJndiProperties;
```

and then

```
for (final String name: myJndiProperties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    System.out.println(myJndiProperties.getProperty(name));
}
```

How do I do the same for the properties file ? How do I combine both property entries in JNDI and property file as one `PropertiesArray`.

The following is not working:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="propertiesArray">
    <list>
      <ref bean="myJndiProperties" />
      <value>classpath:config.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

I am using Spring 3.2.5 with Java 7.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8999771/227140

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Jndi Context and PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8998704/spring-jndi-context-and-propertyplaceholderconfigurer)

Comment: @beny23: Its not a duplicate question. As I want to combine both properties in a single array in my XML and then access it from my class. I don't want any property name hardcoded in my class in any manner for accessing the value.

Comment: Don't use a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` for that. Use `<util:properties />` for that. Also I strongly suggest to use `<context:property-placeholder />` instead of `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. What is there reason you need the full properties instead of using placeholders?