# how to set value in web.xml based on the environment

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-3

I'm using sprint 3.1 profiles and have the following code in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value> 
</context-param>
```

In order to deploy to the test environment, my workflow currently requires me to change the property value to `test`, then make a jar and deploy it. However, I'd like to decouple from explicitly making this change.

I want the workflow to be just build the war and deploy it to test. The test environment should have some variable set the `spring.profiles.active` variable to `test`.

**Question**

How do I set a variable, `spring.profiles.active`, in tomcat7 and configure the `web.xml` so that it instead reads the variable from servers configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Environment tag in Tomcat. Then in your code, use Context's lookup method.

Edit: An example (see the question):
[Read a Environment Variable in Java with Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979958/read-a-environment-variable-in-java-with-websphere)

Comment: hmm I see how to set the variable in tomcat. but how can i access it from my web.xml? Will I have to make applicationConfiguration class especially to set this variable or is there a way to do it directly from web.xml itself.